# How to get url content identified in python without specifing the tags, and removing garbage?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

**How to get url content identified in python without specifing the tags, and removing garbage?**

I know the usual approach, getting data from urlopen and then BeautifulSoup to identify the tag of the content. ***What I really want to know that is there any generic method or library to do this without specifying tags.***

Comment: You don't know what you are searching for, but you definitely want it to be extracted?

Comment: Can you give a simple example of what you mean, and what you've attempted? See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Also, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read about [ask].

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract text from HTML:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
soup = BeautifulSoup(html) 
text = soup.get_text()
```